# How to set multi-language name to a db field in validation error message on laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have i little question about how to manage db fields name inside error message after laravel 4 validation.

To validate form, i used eloquent like follow :

```
public static function validate($input)
    {
        $validation = array(
            'rules' => array(
                'title'     => 'required|min:5'
            ),
            'messages' => array(
                'title.required'            => 'Inserer un titre!'
            )
        );

        return Validator::make($input, $validation['rules'], $validation['messages']);
    }
```

To translate error messages i used this github repo : https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel4-lang

Every thing works fine exept translation of the attribute (db column) name. I have no idea how to do this, any suggestion?

```
fr : Le texte **title** doit contenir au moins 5 caractères.
en : The **title** must be at least 5 characters.
```

(Title stay in english in each case.)

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to provide custom field names for the validation error messages.

First is using the language config file app/lang/LANG/validation.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Attributes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
| with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
| of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
|
*/

'attributes' => array('foo' => 'Bar'),
```

This will generate validation errors for foo field such "The Bar must be..." instead of "The foo must be ...".

The second way is not documented. You can provide the custom array on runtime using the setAttributeNames() method of the Validator class:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
    $validator->setAttributeNames(array('foo' => 'Bar'));
    if ($validator->passes())
        ...
```